# Downloading a file with a Primefaces Button with ajax=false

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, itext

Ok so I have the following problem when I am trying to create a pdf on jsf, if I add ajax=false it generates a pdf, but I am not able to access my data from the form, when I take ajax=false from my butto i am able to access data from my form but my pdf is not generated.

Here is my function

```
public void createPDF() {
        try {
            System.out.println("create pdf " + fichaPlinianDM.getFichaPlinian().getTaxon().getNombreCientificoTaxon());
            String nombre = "name"; // fichaPlinianDM.getFichaPlinian().getTaxon().getNombreCientificoTaxon();
            System.out.println("create pdf " + nombre);

            ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
            ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + nombre + ".pdf\"");

            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, ec.getResponseOutputStream());
            document.open();
            buildPDFContent(document);
            document.close();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I get a null pointer exception if I try to access fichaPlinianDM.getFichaPlinian()

fichaPlinianDM is a managedproperty

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{fichaPlinianDM}")
    private FichaPlinianDM fichaPlinianDM;
```

buildPDFContent is a function  that generates the body of the pdf.  These are the "buttons" i tested on.

```
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{fichaPlinianBusquedaController.test}"
        ajax="false">
        <p:graphicImage library="images" name="pdf.png" />
    </p:commandLink>

    <p:commandButton value="Exportar PDF"
        process="@this,:fichaPlinianAdminForm:fichaPlinianFormularioEntero"
        actionListener="#{fichaPlinianBusquedaController.createPDF()}"
         />
```

Comment: So downloading a plain text file works?

Comment: I can download a pdf file, but I cannot get the info from my form, if I add random info it works.  But if I try to recover info from fichaPlinianDM with ajax="false" it doesnt work

Comment: That was not my question. This is afaics not itext related. And search Stackoverflow about downloading and ajax

Comment: I did, how do you think I got that code and that is how I know to add ajax="false", it was one of Balusc answers

Comment: Yeah you are right it is not related to itext, it is mostly primefaces and ajax

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=afaics ;-) Your title is still misleading. The way it is put, it works... Your problem is combining inputs and download in one form? Does it work with an `h:commandLink` and `h:commandButton` Most likely not even PrimeFaces specific? Try and also reate an [mcve]...